# How to display colors when typing their names in R studio console?

Tags: r, rstudio

When I was using R studio v.4.2.2. on another computer, when I typed a colour, like `"dark green"`, the word `"dark green"` was coloured in dark green (something like this).

[image]

I am now running R 4.0.3. on another computer and this doesn't happen anymore.

[image]

I checked in Tools > Global options > Appearance but found nothing. My current theme is Dracula. Is there a way to set this option? Does it depend from R studio version or is an external package?

Comment: https://community.rstudio.com/t/after-updating-rstudio-color-names-are-highlighted/155600

Comment: Thanks. I'll update R studio and check that option!